# Consider the following table representing the distribution of the discrete random variable x:

Tags: statistics, random-variables, discrete-optimization

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline X & -4 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\ \hline f(x)=P(X=x) & 0.1& 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.4 \\\hline\end{array}$$

Compute:
a) \begin{array}E(x)&=\sum_x xf(x)\\&=(-4\cdot 0.1)+0+(1\cdot 0.2)+(4\cdot0.4) \\ 
    &=-0.4+0.2+1.6 \\
    &=1.4 \end{array}

b)\begin{align}E(X^2-X+1)&=\sum_x (x^2-x+1)f(x)\\&=((-4)^2-(-4)+1)\cdot0.1+(0^2-0+1)\cdot 0.3+(1^2-1+1)\cdot 0.2+(4^2-4+1)\cdot 0.4 \\ 
  \\&=2.1+0.3+0.2+5.2 
  \\&=7.8 \end{align}

c) \begin{align}V(X)&=\sum x^2p-\mu^2\\&=(1.6+0+0.2+6.4)-(1.4)^2 
\\&=8.2-1.96  
\\&=6.24 \end{align}

d) \begin{align}\sigma_X&=\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}\\&=\sqrt{6.24}\\&=\frac{2\sqrt{39}}5\\&=2.497999199\end{align}

This is the work I did I was wondering if I did someone could reassure me or give me any tips if I did something wrong. Thanks in advance! P.S. Feel free to fix/adjust any symbols in the formating.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in part $c$, when you compute $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$.

$1.6+0+0.2+6.4=8.2 \neq 5$.

After obtaining $E(X^2)$ in part $c$, I will use it to check my answer in part $b$. Notice that $$E(X^2-X+1)=E(X^2)-E(X)+1$$

Comment: Oops, I forgot a negative (-) in front of the 1.6 and is my b wrong?

Comment: yes, there is a careless mistake.

Comment: is it the brackets around the -4?

Comment: why is the second term $0$? Anyway, for your part $c$, what should $(-0.4)^2$ be equal to?

Comment: I think my b) is correct now. Could you comfirm? And I don't understand where you see $(-0.4)^2$

Comment: Your $b$ seems fine now. I make a mistake in $c$ earlier. my question should be why is there a negative term in $\sum x^2p(x)$

Comment: I think I figured it out, and I then fixed d) since it was based of c).

Comment: congratulations.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for your help! :) Have a great day, evening or night.